# Does the word "indefatigable" have positive or negative connotation?

Tags: british-english, connotation

Example usage:

> Terence, you have indefatigable enthusiasm. The effect it has on people is inspiring.

In the sense of exuberance, but you feel positively about it.

Comment: It just means *tireless*.  Can *tireless* ever be negative? Yes.

Comment: It has a negative connotation if you're asked to read it aloud with no warning, since no one can remember how it's pronounced.

Comment: If you feel positively about it  then it has a positive connotation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On its own: positive.

Modifying a neutral quality: positive.

However, it's not incorrect to use it as a modifier of a negative quality, so the obviously negative "your indefatigable stupidity continues to amaze me" is a valid use, too.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, *indefatigable* is a word with positive connotations ([here](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/indefatigable)). The [repeated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMS_Indefatigable_(R10)) [use](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMS_Indefatigable_(1909)) of [indefatigable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMS_Indefatigable_(1784)) as a warship name underlines the general tone of approval.

Comment: I understand the idea of describing an inanimate object as indefatigable, but I was unsure whether it could positively describe a person's character.

Comment: The OED has plenty of citations for *indefatigable* where it does not appear to have a particularly positive aspect.  Yes, saying that someone is “tireless” does seem in general positive, but consider “relentless”.

Comment: Though I agree it's largely positive, be wary using it with reference to a person's character, though, as the situation is much more complex there.

Answer (score -2):

The word 'indefatigable' is a positive word. It means persisting or working tirelessly. The word tireless itself gives out postitivty and optimism, if used as an adjective for somebody. Hence, it has a positive connotation.