# The 'de' in indefatigable

Tags: etymology

From [indefatigable](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/indefatigable):

> ADJECTIVE
>
> (of a person or their efforts) persisting tirelessly. ‘an indefatigable defender of human rights’
>
> Origin
>
> Early 17th century: from French, or from Latin indefatigabilis, from in- ‘not’ + de- ‘away, completely’ + fatigare ‘wear out.'

Is the *de-* the same as in *deactivate*? The origin of *deactivate* is not given in that dictionary.

I'm wondering why the word is not simply "infatigable" or even "unfatigable." Why is *de-* there? What is its function?

Comment: See also [Does the word “indefatigable” have positive or negative connotation?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/104943/217285) for more on usage.

Comment: related: [Why does “attach” have two Ts but “detach” only one?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/242857/why-does-attach-have-two-ts-but-detach-only-one)

Comment: The Online Etymology Dictionary is a recommended resource for researching questions about etymology. Doesn't their article explain the etymology here? A Google search for "indefatigable etymology" also provides useful information.

Comment: Questions about the etymology of English words are on topic. Even if the answer turns out to be that the "de-" prefix is not a functional prefix in this case because the word was borrowed "as is" from another language. This is because, generally speaking, the construction chosen by the people who borrowed a word into English should shed light on the originally intended English meaning. It is well worth asking about all the parts of the construction, including affixes.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*OED* places the etymological breakdown of indefatigable as this:

> Latin *indēfatīgābilis* , < (in- prefix) + dēfatīgāre to wear out

In the case of ***in-***, the prefix is functioning as you expected:

> to express negation or privation

The prefix ***de-***, which derives from Latin, can have several meanings.  One of them is "undoing something," which is what makes "indefatigable" sound as though it means "not able to undo fatigue," or, in other words, stuck fatigued.

However, the Latin ***de-*** prefix has other meanings, primarily these:

- **down** as in *depress*
- **off or away** as in *decline*
- **imposing indignity** as in *delude*, *deride*, or *deceive*.

It's likely that in the case of Latin *dēfatīgāre* the *de-* prefix functions to mean *down*.  Think of *indefatigable* as something akin to **undepressed**.  Such a nonce word would not mean "**pressed**," but rather "***not pressed downward***."   Similarly, **indefatigable** doesn't mean "**fatigable**" but rather "***not able to be pulled down by fatigue***."

Comment: OK, this is exactly what I needed! You've even included a somewhat similar example *undepressed* which makes the situation clearer to me. Thank you for the very clear and accessible explanation.

Comment: Good answer. Not *tired down*, er, *tired out*...

Comment: Good answer, but isn't **decline** another example of the _de_ prefix meaning down? I see it as the opposite of **incline** originally meaning to slope upwards. The _turn aside_ or _turn down_ usage seems, to me, to have been adopted later (though still hundreds of years ago). I'm not criticising, just asking.

Comment: @BoldBen according to OED, the earliest meaning of "decline" was "*To turn or bend aside; to deviate (from the straight course); to turn away.*"  From Latin *dēclīnāre - to turn or bend away or aside from the straight course*.  In an etymology note they actually address your question:  "In the sense-development the prefix de- has also been taken in the sense ‘down’, of which there is little trace in Latin dēclīnāre."

Comment: ... So the "down" sense has had an impact in later senses of the word "decline," which makes sense.  But the Latin roots themselves are using the sense "off or away"